# MATLAB publish from a class

Tags: matlab, oop, publish

I am currently trying to publish some results in MATLAB. It works with scripts/functions. But if I try to use it inside a class and publish a function it doesn't work any more. Here is an example:

```
classdef main

    properties 
    end

    methods
        function M = main(boolRawData)

            publish('plotResults(M)');

        end

        function plotResults(M)

            %% Show something

        end 
    end
end
```

Comment: Do you get an error message? Or does it run but the publishing part shows no result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Publishing basically works with scripts (there are some aspects of it that work with functions, but basically it's about scripts).

Make a script that creates an instance `M` of your class, and calls `plotResults(M)` on it. Then publish the script.

Comment: but the class code is in a separate  file and it won't get published

Comment: Only the script gets published

Comment: That’s right @VisheshMangla , you can basically only publish scripts, not classes.

Comment: I found that live scripts were better to use. Make the document there and then export to pdf.Although for he classes I have to do 'paste code' in a separate cell.

Comment: You can use the command `type filename` to display the contents of a file. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/type.html